# How can I delete a quotation mark and comma at the end of every line?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Suppose I have the following text, how can I delete single quotation marks and comma in each line end? I know I can use `x` command and delete `'` and `,`  line by line. But are there any more clever way to do this? <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> doesn't work here.

```
index',
wind_code',
date',
acct_rcv',
acct_payable',
adminexpensetogr',
debttoassets',
finaexpensetogr',
monetary_cap',
operateexpensetogr',
salescashintoor',
tot_assets',
arturn',
assetsturn',
bps',
cashtocurrentdebt',
cfps',
current',
currentdebttodebt',
eps_basic',
fin_exp_is',
grossprofitmargin',
invturn',
longdebttodebt',
net_cash_flows_oper_act',
net_profit_is',
netprofitmargin',
optoebt',
quick',
roa',
roe',
tot_cur_liab',
tot_liab',
tot_oper_rev',
tot_profit',
wgsd_assets',
wgsd_stkhldrs_eq',
yoy_or',
yoy_equity',
yoyprofit',
growth_totalequity'
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `:help :s`…

```
:%s/',
```

With `:help :normal`…

```
:%norm $xx
```

With `:help recording`…

```
qq
$xxj
q
:,$norm @q
```

or…

```
qq
$xxj
q
@q@@@@@@@@@@ (as many times as needed)
```

With `:h .`…

```
/',<CR>
2x
n.n.n.n. (as many times as needed)
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer:

```
:%s/',$//g
```

delete `',` ending in those lines that match the pattern.